# What is the meaning of "right"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

What's the correct meaning of the right in the following sentence:

> "when the right virtuous Edward Wotton and I were at the Emperor's Court together ".

Comment: It's an honorific. Related: [The Right Honourable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Right_Honourable).

Comment: See also "Right Honourable".  Right honourable and right virtuous are honorifics; right is an intensifier, like "very."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, *right* is an intensifier. If you have a copy of the Oxford English Dictionary handy, this is sense A.III.13.a of "right, adj. and int.":

> Of a person: justly entitled to a name or title; having the true character of; true, real, veritable.

So, the *Right Virtuous Edward Wotton* is truly virtuous.

The OED then goes on to say (and I agree with this impressionistically) that it is weakened in later use, where it approaches sense A.III.13.e:

> *colloq.* (chiefly *Brit.* and *Irish English*). As an intensifier (usu. in derogatory and ironical contexts): complete, absolute, total, utter. Cf. *right Charley* at Charley *n. 6.*

I would say that the honorific use is a fossilised relic, and that *right* is only used now in the derogatory or ironic sense. For example:

> 1973   *Observer* 14 Jan. 1/4   ‘The Government did not know that there was no settlement in writing, and how could an order apply to something which did not exist,’ he said. ‘The Government made a right mess of it.’